# Bendy Bones Deforming when Importing to Unity from Blender

Tags: animation, bones, unity

I have recently created some vine animations that grow from the base of a plant. I used multiple bendy bones per vine that would stretch and move the mesh. However when I import it into unity it doesn't look as smooth and there are bugs within the mesh that make it look super weird. I was wondering if there were any settings within blender or unity I could use to fix this problem? First image is within unity with the bugs and the second image is within blender and is an example of what it should look like.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bendy bones is a function unique to Blender, which can't be exported to Unity: you have to create the effect you want in Blender using standard bones, then export it to Unity.

Comment: The same kind of effects can be achieved using [spline IK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3Fts3TEjew)